# vb6 dll in .net REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG

Tags: vb.net, dll, vb6, compiled

Hope someone could help me..
I created a vb6 dll which suppose to use the printer.print method since i want an easier printer functions.. it runs smoothly in same computer using vb.net 2012 , the problem is after publishing it in newly installed OS with prerequisite installed computers

p.s. already tried installing vb6 IDE and tried the actual printer.print without a problem

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your installer properly registers the DLL. Given your Title, this is probably the first culprit.  But there will also be some (many?) VB6 runtimes which need to be installed as well.  I am not sure if the standard .NET setup maker knows how to determine what they are and newer machines you install on may not already have them.

When you installed the VB6 IDE you probably fixed the runtimes issue for THAT machine, so it probably has to do with the DLL being registerd.  For more installs, you may have to create a mini VB6 installer for the project to install the runtimes.

What is the target OS?

Comment: my target CPU x86, i tried to install it in windows7 32bit.. my current OS is windows7 64bit.. btw, i also tried regsrv32 on my dll it gives an error.. The module "xxx.dll" was not loaded but entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found .. Thanks for reply

Comment: You are also going to need the AxInterop stuff, if they arent there it wont run and would produce that error.  You might get a clue by looking closer at the exception detail is `RESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)) ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`.  I dont think it is something else (just might be at a differnet level) because REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG means something isnt registered.  Also look into DependencyWalker (free) to tell you what other files go along with it and probably need to be registered.

Comment: +1. Minor correction. The basic VB6 runtime is now part of Windows (since Vista) so there *may* not be any VB6 runtimes to distribute. The OP should totally check though, as you've advised.

Comment: Thanks MarkJ, I forgot that for the MS files but I also had in mind any controls/helpers/widgets being used.